# How to do perspective correction in camera calibration matlab toolbox

Tags: matlab, perspective

I am using matlab camera calibration toolbox to do camera distortion and perspective correction. under the toolbox, I insert another image of the ckeckerboard (not used in calibration), the program can calculate the extrinsic parameters R_ext and T_ext of that image. I want to use these rotation matrix and translation matrix to do perspective correction of that image. But I am always failed and I can not figure out the problem. I just use the image grid x_kk(1:1280*1:960), and equation inv(R_ext)*(x_kk-T_ext) to get the world frame coordinate, and then use triscatterinterp function in the matlab to link the image with calculated object position. in my tuition,then I should get perspection corrected checkerboard (no tilt no rotation and no distortion), but the result is wrong.

I am just started in machine version, so anyone can help me?